# promises with a recursive call in error Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```
requestReport()
.then(getReportData)
.then(checkReportStatus)
.then(handleData)

checkReportStatus = (data) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(data.status === 'completed')
            resolve(data)
        else {
            setTimeout(() => getReportData(), 1000)
        }
```

So I make a report request first, then I need to check whether report was produced(status would turn into completed). If it is not completed yet , I need to call getReportData again. But I'm really confused with promises. My code is actually many lines and there is around 15 chainings going.  What is the correct way to make call if report is not completed, so that when it becomes completed it can just continue from  handleData?

edit1: typo

Comment: `=` is not `===`

Comment: There are 2 errors here: there should be an ```=``` between ```checkReportStatus``` and ```(data)``` and ```if(data.status = 'completed')``` should be ```if(data.status == 'completed')```

Comment: thats a typo by me, it is just a pseudo code, I m more interested in making a recursive call inside promise until i get answer of completed so that i could continue with data parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `getReportData()` returns a promise that resolves with the data (which it appears to in your `.then()` chain) and doesn't need any input parameters from `requestReport()`, then you can just do this:

```
// utility function that returns a promise that resolves after a delay
// useful for inserting a delay into a promise chain
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}


requestReport()
  .then(getReportData)
  .then(checkReportStatus)
  .then(handleData)

function checkReportStatus(data) {
    if (data.status === 'completed') {
        return data;
    } else {
        // retry after a delay
        // add retry promise to the current promise chain
        return delay(1000).then(getReportData);
    }
}
```

If you need the results of `requestReport()` as arguments to `getReportData()`, then you will have pass that info into the promise chain so the retry on `getReportData()` can use it.  You'd have to show us more detail (what data is returned from `requestReport()` and what data is needed by `getReportData()`) for us to make a specific recommendation on how best to do that.

Comment: That has been a good enough answer for me, thank you for it. My code is really messed up and long.

Answer (score -1):

```
checkReportStatus (data) => {
    if (data.status === 'completed') {
        return data;
    } else {
        // retry after a delay
       delay(1000).then(checkReportStatus(data));
    }
```

}

try call checkReportStatus(data).

Comment: The `data` does not change with this solution so calling `checkReportStatus(data)` again on the same data won't accomplish anything.  Plus, `delay()` is not defined in your answer either (it appears you copied the idea from my answer, but didn't show an implementation).

Comment: You really ought to delete both your answers as neither one provides an answer to the question and you are just accumulating downvotes (negative reputation) that could even prevent you from participating in some parts of the site if you continue.